# automatically create ActiveRecord parent for association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

In my app i have:

```
class Wallet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true
  has_many   :transactions, :class_name => 'WalletTransaction'
end

class WalletTransaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :wallet
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one    :wallet, :as => :owner
  has_many   :wallet_transactions, :through => :wallet, :source => :transactions
end
```

How do I automatically create a `Wallet` for a User who has none when a `WalletTransaction` is added for that User. Example:

```
@user = User.find(1)
@wallet_transaction = @User.wallet_transactions.new(attributes)
```

If the above code is run and the student has no `Wallet` record in the database, the app should automatically create one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `first_or_create`:

```
@wallet_transaction = @user.wallet_transactions.first_or_create(attributes)
```

UPDATE:
I misunderstood the question, you should create the wallet first if none exists and then refer to the transactions through the @wallet instance. Doing so also ensures that the wallet_id of WalletTransaction is always referred to the correct wallet.

```
@wallet = @user.wallet.first_or_create
@wallet_transaction = @wallet.transactions.new(attributes)
```

Comment: This can't be correct. I want to automatically create a new Wallet for the User. This code wouldn't work if the user has no Wallet record to begin with.

Comment: @FavouriteChigozieOnwuemene hi, i misunderstood the question. I've updated the answer above